# Header image overriding nav functionality

Tags: html, css, header, positioning

I'm having some issues with my header. There are two images. One a background tile that is repeated on the x axis. A logo image that is centered and navigation buttons two on the left and right of it. When I positioned the logo in the center, the nav links to the right of the logo lost functionality. No hovering or linking. Why would this happen? How do I fix it?

I am new to this, so please go gentle if I asked a question that has been answer thousands of times before. I googled my issue and cannot figure out what to do. Hopefully, someone here can help me.

Here is a link to see the problem and the code.

http://jsbin.com/iqoQuGAy/11/edit

here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>why?</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<!--HEADER -->
<header>
<div id="pageHeader">
<a href="#" id="logo"></a>
<!--NAVIGATION -->
<nav id="mainNav">
<ul>
<li id="about-link"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
<li id="work-link"><a href="#work">work</a></li>
<li id="contact-link"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
<li id="resume-link"><a href="#resume">resume</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header> <!-- end header -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
/*Global styles*/

/*limited reset*/
html, body, div, section, article, aside, header, hgroup, footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, address, time, span, em, strong, img, ol, ul, li, figure, canvas, video, th, td, tr {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
vertical-align:baseline;
font: inherit;
}

/*html5 display rule*/
address, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, menu, nav, section, summary {
display: block;}


html {
background-color: #E7E9D1;
background-image: url(http://s24.postimg.org/4rcaja0lh/image.png);
}

body
{
position: relative;
font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}

/*header styles*/
header
{
background-image: url("http://s7.postimg.org/59ft4upyf/header_bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 200;
}
#pageHeader
{
height: 128px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 960px;
}
#pageHeader:after
{
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 425px;
top: 0;
background: url('http://s18.postimg.org/5ktpz4rid/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat scroll;
}

/*nav styles*/
#mainNav {
font-size: 18px;
list-style: none outside none;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#mainNav li {
display: inline;
}

#mainNav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: rgb(252,250,230);
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
}

#mainNav a:hover {
color: #9f9e8f;
}

#mainNav #about-link {
margin-right: 50px;
}
#mainNav #work-link {
margin-right: 0px;
}
#mainNav #contact-link {
margin-left: 160px;
}
#mainNav #resume-link {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're #pageHeader div waz set to `width: 100%;` which was covering your links. Giving it a width fixes this:

```
#pageHeader:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 425px;
    top: 0;
    background: url('http://s18.postimg.org/5ktpz4rid/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat scroll;
}
```

Here is the fixed link: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/iFaMITaxU/1/)

Comment: Enijar and badAdviceGuy - you guys are so awesome and that totally fixed my issue! Thank you!

Comment: Just click the check. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the logo is added via an `:after` class with a width of `100%`. Since it's an `:after` class it will display on a higher z-index than the rest of the element (and thus cover up your other links).

If you change your CSS entry for the logo to below it should fix your issue:

```
#pageHeader:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 left: 425px;
 top: 0;
 background: url('http://s18.postimg.org/5ktpz4rid/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `position: relative;` from the `body` rule.